# Iterating a panels controls results in an index out of bounds error. Why?

Tags: delphi, loops, indexing, controls

I am using Delphi 7 (Yes, I hear the guffaws). I have a tabbed notebook that I want certain controls to appear only in a sequence where the prior control is finished correctly. For each page in the notebook, I have a named sheet. And for the controls on that sheet, I use the tag property to determine whether they are visible at each step. Some steps result in one new control showing, some steps have as many as five controls popping into view. I thought to simply iterate through the controls on any tab sheet that's in view and turn off anything with a tag greater than the current step value. On the page in question, there appear to be 23 controls in all, some labels that are always in view, some edit fields that pop up into view and some arrow-shaped buttons for advancing when a newly popped up field gets changed. Seemed simple enough, except I kept generating Index out of range errors. The sequence would shut down with out a detailed error message for EurekaLog, not anything opened up that should have been. I finally 'resolved' the issue by plugging in a check for the NAME of the control I knew was last in the list and quitting the loop at that point. I also added the extra test for Kounter.tag <> zero to avoid leaving the Submit and Cancel buttons on in some routes. Ideas why the Kounter just kept on past 23?

```
procedure TFrmMain.VizToggleWTP;
var
  kounter: Integer;
  kontrol: TControl;
  Kontrolz: Integer;
begin
  Kontrolz := sheetPrintouts.ControlCount;
  for Kounter := 1 to Kontrolz
  do begin
    // To avoid index error, check for the Cancel Button and exit at that point
    if sheetPrintouts.Controls[kounter].Name = 'BtnCancelwtp'
      then Break;
    if (sheetPrintouts.Controls[Kounter]) is TNXEdit
      then begin
        kontrol := TNXEdit(sheetPrintouts.Controls[Kounter]);
        kontrol.visible := (kontrol.Tag <= wtpStep);
        end;
    if (sheetPrintouts.Controls[Kounter]) is TJvShapedButton
      then begin
        kontrol := TJvShapedButton(sheetPrintouts.Controls[Kounter]);
        kontrol.visible := ((kontrol.Tag <= wtpStep) and (kontrol.Tag <> 0));
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: -1 If you ask a question, you should have the common courtesy to listen to the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace

```
for Kounter := 1 to Kontrolz do
```

with

```
for Kounter := 0 to Kontrolz-1 do
```

since the `Controls` array is zero-based.

For instance, if there are three controls, they are indexed `0, 1, 2` and not `1, 2, 3`.

Comment: Andreas, I want the first control to always show, so i don't test for zero based control. But even if that was necessary, the index error would be contained because 1 to x is a subset of 0 to x.

Comment: @GM: In your loop, the last value of `Kounter` is `Kontrolz`, and `Controls[Kontrolz]` doesn't exist; the last control is `Controls[Kontrolz-1]`. Indeed, if there are `3` controls, the last one is called `2`; there is no control indexed `3`.

Comment: And the error also was there for Kontrolz-1 and Kontrols+1.

Comment: @GM: You should think before you implement code, not add `+1`s and `-1`s in a trial and error-like fashion!

Comment: @GMMugford Why are you arguing? The `Controls[]` property uses zero-based indexing. End of story. You could find that out from the documentation.

Comment: David, not arguing zero-based at all. Andreas suggested I start the For loop with zero. I don't want to toggle off the zero control. So I started with one deliberately. Given that 1..x is a subset of 0..x, I should not be out of bounds. I also indicated, in trying to stomp on the error, that I tried ending the loop with Kontrols-1 initially. And when that failed, I tried Kontrolz+! and Kontrolz. All failed until I included the test for the BtnCancelwtp. Is it possible SOME OTHER error got in the way of Kontrolz-1 and I fixed two errors at the same time? Sure. I am confused.

Comment: Zero based means valid indices are 0 to N-1 inclusive

Comment: Having said it is possible I am confused, I am about to retry Kontrolz-1 as the top boundary again, and disable the Btncancelwtp test. It is the polite thing to do.

Comment: David, you keep hammering on a non-issue.

Comment: @GM: Sure, you can start at `1` if you like. But it is absolutely impossible to end at `Kontrolz`! `Kontrolz-1` is OK.

Comment: Non-issue?! Zero based is the issue. Where you start counting determines where you finish. Valid indices are 0 to N-1 inclusive. End of story.

Comment: Andreas, thanks for reading it all the way through and identifying the issue, although I did have to remove the and (kontrol.Tag <> 0) test to make sure the cancel button appeared as needed. It's always nice to get help clearing the fog.